# Expand_range argument in mlr3 for visualization of qda

Tags: r, graph-visualization, mlr3

so I am trying to vizualize the prediction of an QDA-learner using the mlr3viz-package in R. The vizualisation (via plot_learner_prediction) works fine, however everytime I try to expand the range of the predictions via the expand_range attribute nothing happens.

```
pl = plot_learner_prediction(learner, task, expand_range = 3)
```

Nothing happens when I add or change the expand_range argument. Does anyone know how to handle this argument? I had a look into the documentation https://mlr3viz.mlr-org.com/reference/plot_learner_prediction.html but it doesn't really help me.

Thanks a lot already!

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.